# Why is my Kivy AnchorLayout stuck in the bottom left?

Tags: kivy

I have the following code in `my.kv` file:

```
<UIWidget>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Button:
            size_hint: None, None
            text: 'Build'
```

UI Widget is an empty Widget subclass.

```
class UIWidget(Widget):
    pass
```

My root widget loads UIWidget into itself as follows:

```
class SimplifiedGameWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.layout = RelativeLayout(size_hint=(None, None))
        self.layout.size = (1024, 768)
        ui_widget = UIWidget()
        ui_widget.size_hint = (1, 1)
        self.layout.add_widget(ui_widget)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

 class MyApp(App):
     def build(self):
         return SimplifiedGameWidget()
```

(Full code: http://pastie.org/10791067)

What I expect to get:

- GameWidget > RelativeLayout > UIWidget all sized at window size
- The AnchorLayout that is a child of UIWidget in the top right of the screen
- The Button in the AnchorLayout at the default size in the top right.

What I actually get:

- GameWidget > RelativeLayout > UIWidget all sized at window size
- The AnchorLayout that is a child of UIWidget in the bottom left of the screen, at 100x100px
- The Button in the AnchorLayout at the default size in the bottom left at 100x100px

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: like this http://pastie.org/10791093 ?

Answer (score 2):

`Widget`s don't affect the size or position of their children, with or without `size_hint`/`pos_hint` - this is the purpose of `Layout`s. Since the default position of a `Widget` is `(0, 0)`, the `AnchorLayout` ends up in the lower-left corner, with the default size `(100, 100)`. I would maybe switch the `SimplifiedGameWidget` to extend `FloatLayout` instead, and make `UIWidget` extend `AnchorLayout` directly instead of containing one:

```
<UIWidget>:
    anchor_x: 'right'
    ...

<SimplifiedGameWidget>:
    UIWidget
```

and:

```
class UIWidget(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class SimplifiedGameWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass
```