# Kivy (kv language) StackLayout Issue and Boundary Issue

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to Kivy and still working out the best way to use it. Currently, I'm taking an example from their repo (textsize demo) and attempting to use layout concepts in a personal project.

At the end of the day, all I want is a "navbar" at the top of my screen and a content section below it. At the moment, I'm trying to accomplish this with a BoxLayout which includes a StackLayout (nav items) and a GridLayout (other content).

My Code Snippet:

```
<WindowWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        StackLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Test1'
            Label:
                text: 'Test1.1'
        Label:
            text: 'Test2'
```

This code produces this: [Kivy Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pirb3.png).

I don't understand why label 1.1 is pushed down on top of label 2 rather than appearing beside label 1.

I added the following code taken from the kivy examples hoping the height setting would add some clarity, but I get the error below:

Code:

```
<StackLayout>:
    size_hint_y: None
    spacing: dp(6)
    padding: dp(6), dp(4)
    height: self.minimum_height
```

Error:

> Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your
>   code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute

This is caused by my inclusion of the "height: self.minimum_height" line. However, this works in the demo, so I'm not sure how I managed to screw it up. I'll include the example's kv code below for reference.

The original:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    HeadingLabel:
        text: 'These modify all demonstration Labels'

    StackLayout:
        # Button is a subclass of Label and can be sized to text in the same way

        Button:
            text: 'Reset'
            on_press: app.reset_words()

        ToggleButton:
            text: 'Shorten'
            on_state:
                app.shorten=self.state=='down'

        ToggleButton:
            text: 'max_lines=3'
            on_state:
                app.max_lines=3 if self.state=='down' else 0

        Spinner:
            text: 'bottom'
            values: 'bottom', 'middle', 'top'
            on_text: app.valign=self.text

        Spinner:
            text: 'left'
            values: 'left', 'center', 'right', 'justify'
            on_text: app.halign=self.text

    GridLayout:
        id: grid_layout
        cols: 2
        height: cm(6)
        size_hint_y: None

        HeadingLabel:
            text: "Default, no text_size set"

        HeadingLabel:
            text: 'text_size bound to size'

        DemoLabel:
            id: left_content
            disabled_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

        DemoLabel:
            id: right_content
            text_size: self.size
            padding: dp(6), dp(6)

    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Disable left'
        on_state:
            left_content.disabled=self.state=='down'

    # Need one Widget without size_hint_y: None, so that BoxLayout fills
    # available space.
    HeadingLabel:
        text: 'text_size width set, size bound to texture_size'
        text_size: self.size
        size_hint_y: 1

    DemoLabel:
        id: bottom_content
        # This Label wraps and expands its height to fit the text because
        # only text_size width is set and the Label size binds to texture_size.
        text_size: self.width, None
        size: self.texture_size
        padding: mm(4), mm(4)
        size_hint_y: None

# The column heading labels have their width set by the parent,
# but determine their height from the text.
<HeadingLabel@Label>:
    bold: True
    padding: dp(6), dp(4)
    valign: 'bottom'
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    text_size: self.width, None
    size_hint_y: None

<ToggleButton,Button>:
    padding: dp(10), dp(8)
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size

# This inherits Button and the modifications above, so reset size
<Spinner>:
    size: sp(68), self.texture_size[1]

<DemoLabel@Label>:
    halign: app.halign
    valign: app.valign
    shorten: app.shorten
    max_lines: app.max_lines

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 68/255.0, 164/255.0, 201/255.0
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

<StackLayout>:
    size_hint_y: None
    spacing: dp(6)
    padding: dp(6), dp(4)
    height: self.minimum_height
```

TYIA

Comment: if WindowWidget class inherits the Widget class. then just inherit from BoxLayout. check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518830/why-is-my-kivy-anchorlayout-stuck-in-the-bottom-left#answer-36520363

Comment: Thanks for the info about widgets. I've altered the code to make BoxLayout the root without the "windowwidget" item. However, it is still showing up like the image posted in the original question. Am I missing something else elementary?

Comment: yep apparently that wasn't the problem. i have set the StackLayout `size_hint_y` to None, it dosn't overlap.

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks mate!